# What does the statement d3.select(#toolTip) do? I am trying to assign the value returned to a var in js.

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
drawTree: function(treeData){
    $('#category-context-menu').hide();
    $('#node-context-menu').hide();
    $("#imageLoading").show();
var toolTip = d3.select("#toolTip");
var header = d3.select("#head");
var header1 = d3.select("#header1");
var header2 = d3.select("#header2");
var memory = d3.select("#memory");
var cpu = d3.select("#cpu");
var utilization = d3.select("#utilization");
```

Just wanted to know how the mapping is done with the jsp file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

d3.select is simply select one element by selector  from the  html page.
if suppose in your jsp file

```
<div id="Id">Hello</div>
```

then after writing this

```
 d3.select("#Id")
```

it will select that particular element from that jsp
But Suppose you want to select multiple elements eg.

```
<div class="multi"></div>
<div class="multi"></div>
<div class="multi"></div>
```

and if you want to select all then you have to simply write

```
 d3.selectAll(".multi")
```

it will select all div.
for basics you can read [Basics of D3](http://www.digital-geography.com/d3-basics-all-you-need-is-a-selection/#.VSuu9dyUe70)

Answer (score 0):

It will give you a D3 wrapped DOM object of the specified selector

You can checkout the details here https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections